# If $f(x) = 4x^2 - 4ax + b$ and $a^2-b$ is a perfect square of a rational number then which one is the right statement

Tags: parity

If :
$f(x) = 4x^2 - 4ax + b$
and $a^2-b$ is a **perfect square** of a rational number then among the following statements below which one is the right statement :

(a)If $a$ is odd , b is even , roots of $f(x) = 0$ are not integer

(b)If $a$ is even , b is odd , roots of $f(x) = 0$ are integer

(c)If $a$ is odd , b is odd , roots of $f(x) = 0$ are not integer

(d)If $a$ is even , b is even , roots of $f(x) = 0$ are not integer

I tried using Parity but I dont have a clear picture , can someone help me out

Comment: The quadratic formula gives $(a\pm \sqrt{a^2-b})/2$

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ integers?

Comment: @DavidP what can we conclude from that ?

Comment: @Bernard Yes they are integers

Comment: If $a,b$ are even, for example, so is the numerator.

Comment: @DavidP yes thanks man i got it
u made my day :)

Comment: @IamRDT; but inthis case is the perfect square of an integer, not merely a rational number.

Comment: @Bernard The multiple choice answers of 'even' and 'odd' were a giveaway that a,b are integers. weird choice of proclaiming it was rational though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a^2-b$ be perfect square of $k$ where $k\in Q$

Roots of $f(x)$ are $\displaystyle \alpha,\beta=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2- b}}{2}=\frac{a\pm k}{2}$

**IF** $a,b$ are integers, then $k$ is also an integer

If $a$ is odd and $b$ is even , then $k$ is odd , therefore $a\pm k$ is even and hence roots of $f(x)$ are integers

Can you similarly check for other options?